# How to get rid of unwanted spaces with \input?

Tags: spacing, input

For my project to bring scripting to (Xe)(La)TeX, I need to execute command lines with `write18`, redirect output to a temporary file, and then insert the produced text using `\input`. I've noticed some extraneous whitespace that occurs right after each output, and I managed to hunt down *one* source down to the most basic part of the equation (I'm observing three different amounts of whitespace; the one discussed here is the smallest amount, so it seems that there is more than a single source for that phenomenon).

here is a 'sub-minimal' MWE:

```
xxxxxxx\\
xxx\input{/tmp/out.txt}xxx\\
xxxx xxx
```

---

Assuming that the contents of said file consists of a single `x` (which I can easily prove by running `cat /tmp/out.txt`:

```
$ cat /tmp/out.txt
x$ ▌
```

See how the `x` is directly followed by the command line prompt), I still get a space after the fourth `x` in the second line of the resulting pdf file. The second line is matching perfectly with the third line, which does contain a deliberate space; it should for all intents and purposes match with the *first* line, of course.

This looks as if — contrary to the descriptions I've read — the command `\input` actually inserts the file contents *plus* (at least) a single (?) `\x20` character into the document.

Can this observation be corroborated? And, importantly: how do i get rid of that extraneous space?

Comment: Try `xxx\input{/tmp/out.txt}\ignorespaces xxx`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

that is correct, your external file has *one* line and the lineend is replaced by a space.

Use `\input{/tmp/out.txt}\unskip` or insert a `%` at the end of the x in the external file: `x%`

Comment: thx a lot! that was real fast!

Comment: @Herbert What if I only want one space after the `\input{}` object? `A \input{file.txt} B` produces *two* spaces before B, whereas `A \input{file.txt}\unskip B` produces *no* space before B. How can I get *one* space?

Comment: Answering my own question: `A \input{file.txt} \unskip \ B`

Answer (score 5):

If the files you input in that way have a single line, then you can define

```
\newcommand{\lineinput}[1]{%
  \begingroup\endlinechar=-1 \input{#1}\endgroup
}
```

which would remove the trailing end of line. Then

```
xxx\lineinput{/tmp/out.txt}xxx
```

will not have the problem.